# i am building a program to manage a pharmacy

Tags: oracle11g

i am building a program to manage a pharmacy and he need a form he can add  photos to his employees...

for example i tried this code:

```
    create table pic(
pic_id number,
pic_name varchar2(20),
pic long raw);
```

but this code need to select the images into trigger when image pressed by this code:

```
declare
x number;
begin
    x:=:pic.pic_id;
    if x=1 then
        read_image_file('D:\test\image\1.jpg','jpg','pic');
    elsif x=2 then
        read_image_file('D:\test\image\2.jpg','jpg','pic');
        elsif x=3 then
        read_image_file('D:\test\image\3.jpg','jpg','pic');
        elsif x=4 then
        read_image_file('D:\test\image\4.jpg','jpg','pic');
        elsif x=5 then
        read_image_file('D:\test\image\5.jpg','jpg','pic');
        end if;
        end;
```

and this not wat i need... i need create a button in employees form to add a photo and this photo be saved like any field in database without this if code.

> 1- i need to know how to create column in oracle database to allow me to insert photos into.
>
> 2- i need to know how to build a field in form to add this photo to database.
>
> 3- i need to know how i can use the bar-code by the bar-code font.

Comment: You have three questions! Congratulations on doing most of the hard work for us. You missed out two steps though: checking to see whether those subquestions had already been asked, and posting them separately. (Your third question seems completely unrelated and should _definitely_ be posted separately.)

Comment: It seems to me like you need tutorials and training more than anything.  I am not sure this is a good fit for StackOverflow.  It really isn't a basic education/training site.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this OraFAQ Forum [discussion](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/60477/) (or, should I say, *tutorial*), where the author, @saadatahmad explained how to do that, and even attached FMBs you can download and work on them.

As of the third question (about the barcode): it is more or less useless in Forms, but people (me included) used it in Reports. If that's what you are asking, then enclose the barcode string into asterisks, such as

```
select '*' || barcode_column || '*' barcode_field
from your_table
```

In Layout editor, choose that field, assign the barcode font to it (such as one of IDAutomation.com ones), run the report and - barcode should be there. If you try to read it with the barcode scanner, it should also be successful; the key *is* in those asterisks.

If you're reading the barcode through a form, no problem - barcode scanner works like a "keyboard" and - through a reader click - does what you'd normally type on the keyboard. So - create an item and read the value. If you set form items to automatically skip to the next item, you'll be able to read whole lot of information which would fit into appropriate items.